# How to use custom loop for Wordpress menus?

Tags: wordpress, loops, drop-down-menu, menu, wordpress-theming

I am using the below code to create a custom WordPress menu for mobile. With this code, nothing is return. Even the menu is not retrieving. Can anyone assist me with this? This is a multilingual website and I am using Polylang for the translations.

```
<?php
                $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items('Mobile Menu');

                if ($menu_items) {
                    echo '<ul class="list-unstyled">';
                    foreach ($menu_items as $menu_item) {
                        if ($menu_item->menu_item_parent == 0) {
                            echo '<li>';
                            if (count_menu_items_by_parent($menu_item->ID, $menu_items)) {
                                echo '<a class="sub-menu-parent" href="javascript:void(0)">' . $menu_item->title . '</a>';
                            } else {
                                echo '<a href="' . $menu_item->url . '">' . $menu_item->title . '</a>';
                            }
                            echo '<ul class="sub-menu">';
                            foreach ($menu_items as $sub_menu_item) {
                                if ($sub_menu_item->menu_item_parent == $menu_item->ID) {
                                    echo '<li><a href="' . $sub_menu_item->url . '">' . $sub_menu_item->title . '</a></li>';
                                }
                            }
                            echo '</ul>';
                            echo '</li>';
                        }
                   }
                   echo '</ul>';
                }

                function count_menu_items_by_parent($parent_ID, $menu_items) {
                    $count = 0;
                    foreach ($menu_items as $menu_item) {
                        if ($menu_item->menu_item_parent == $parent_ID) {
                            $count++;
                        }
                    }
                   return $count;
                }
                ?>
```

Comment: Can you share the count_menu_items_by_parent function  so I can check ? also add a var_dump($menu_items); to check if any item is printed

Comment: @AdrianBiba it is at the bottom of the shared code.

function count_menu_items_by_parent($parent_ID, $menu_items) {
                    $count = 0;
                    foreach ($menu_items as $menu_item) {
                        if ($menu_item->menu_item_parent == $parent_ID) {
                            $count++;
                        }
                    }
                   return $count;
                }